# Почему Safari 12 добавляет черный фон на элементы в фиксированном блоке?

Tags: safari, fixed, background-color

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как решить следующую проблему:
[страница](https://nyris.rocks/about-us/)
OS: macOS Mojave
Браузер: Safari 12

Header фиксированный, при прокрутке добавляется цвет фона. В Safari 12, если прокрутить страницу вниз, затем изменить размер окна и прокрутить вверх, фон шапки становится черным. Либо при ховере на ссылки меню под ними появляется черный фон.

Как убрать это поведение?

Comment: Такого поведения не наблюдается сайте, который вы указали.

Comment: Посмотрите, пожалуйста, страницу https://nyris.rocks/about-us/. И именно такой порядок действий: прокрутка вниз, ресайз окна, прокрутка вверх. Результат такой: https://clip2net.com/s/43GvBv2, хотя шапка должна быть прозрачной.